# How to give priority order for cucumber after hooks

Tags: protractor, cucumber

I have implemented some cucumber after hooks. But without the priority order, I can not control which After hooks should run first. Sample code as follows

```
defineSupportCode(({ After, Before }) => {
After({ tags: '@dismiss_alert_after' }, () => {
    ActionUtil.click(element(by.partialButtonText('Okay')));
});

After(function (testCase: TestCase) {
    const signout: Signout = new Signout();
    return !(testCase.result.status === 'failed') ? 
 signout.signoutApplication() : Promise.resolve();
    });
 });
```

The ends of the test steps execution, first it's should execute the hook '@dismiss_alert_after' for scenarios which tagged as '@dismiss_alert_after' and after that, it should run the signout hook. But it's doesn't. How can I control the order of the hooks? Help much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hooks are executed in the reverse order that they are defined.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/api_reference.md

In Java is possible to configure the step order passing it as argument in the hook annotation, but I've not found docs about it in js, so I suppose it is not supported

Comment: thanks for the reply. yes in java we can define the order